# Error passing in func<type, bool> as a parameter to an async method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, entity-framework-6

I am modifying an existing project to take advantage of EF6 (alpha3) async extension methods.  I have one method that takes a func parameter, which is passed into the linq to entities query.  Here is an example of the working code, pre-async:

```
public IEnumerable<type> GetTypeSet(Func<Type, bool> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(d => d.isPublic == true).Where(predicate).tolist();
    }
```

After applying async:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Type>> GetTypeSet(Func<Type, bool> predicate)
    {
        return await(dbSet.Where(d => d.isPublic == true)
        .Where(predicate)).ToListAsync();
    }
```

At this point, I get an error stating that IEnumerable does not have a definition for ToListAsync.  If I remove `.Where(predicate)` it functions correctly.

I am curious if I am going about this correctly, or if there is a better option for passing in a predicate when working async.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `.Where( predicate )` is using the `IEnumerable.Where` extension method, not `IQueryable.Where`.

This means, the predicate is being run in your app, not on the database server.

If you want to use `IQueryable.Where`, you must pass your predicate as an `Expression<Func<type, bool>>` - an expression tree - not as a delegate.

So, just change your method signature to:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Type>>
  GetTypeSet(Expression<Func<Type, bool>> predicate)
{
  ...
```

Comment: Thats what I was missing.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I assume `ToListAsync` is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>`. You should change the type of the `predicate` parameter to `Expression<Func<Type, bool>>`.

Since `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` all the `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods, like `Where(this IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>)` are available, but are usually not what you are intending to use.

Since `predicate` is a `Func<Type, bool>` the type of

```
dbSet.Where(d => d.isPublic == true)
```

is `IEnumerable<Type>` when you want it to be `IQueryable<Type>`.
Changing the type of `predicate` to `Expression<Func<Type, bool>>` will cause the `Queryable.Where` extension method to be used, which returns an `IQueryable<Item>` as desired.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the details.  Very helpful.  Wish I could choose multiple answers.

Answer (score 3):

You must make the function take an Expression, otherwise the Where extension will fallback on IEnumerable, instead of IQueryable. And ToListAsync is only and extension method on IQueryable.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Type>> GetTypeSet(Expression<Func<Type, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await(dbSet.Where(d => d.isPublic == true)
    .Where(predicate)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Cheers